# .removeClass() only working once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have laid out some images in HTML 4x2. My script is currently enlarging every image using .addClass(), however will only .removeClass() on the first image within the gallery.

How would I make it so as .removeClass() can be applied to every image? - Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fig').delegate('img', 'click', function () {
        $(this).addClass("imgbig");
        $('.xbutton').stop(true, true).fadeTo(800, 1);
        $("#fig").stop(true, true).addClass("f1");
    });

    $('.xbutton').click(function () {
        $('#imgSmall').removeClass("imgbig");
        $('.xbutton').stop(true, true).fadeOut(800, 0);
        $("#fig").stop(true, true).removeClass("f1");
    });
});
```

Comment: `$('#imgSmall').removeClass("imgbig");` You are using an id selector which is intended to select only one node, perhaps it should be $(this).removeClass(...).

Comment: Yeah I did try this, however 'this' would refer to the xbutton, which isn't the image. Christos has posted the solution below. Cheers for the suggestion though man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `$('#imgSmall').removeClass("imgbig")` you select the image with id `imgSmall`, not all the images you have.

I suppose that you should rewrite you callback like below:

```
$('.xbutton').click(function(){
    $(".imgbig").removeClass("imgbig");
    $('.xbutton').stop(true, true).fadeOut(800, 0);
    $("#fig").stop(true, true).removeClass("f1");
});
```

Comment: Yeah that's worked a treat, cheers. I feel like a doughnut now >_<

Comment: @Filthy_Rich you are welcome dude. I am glad that I hepled :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the html please. I'm guessing you have a bunch of images, when you click on them, the image expands and when you click on the close button the image shrinks?

```
$(function() {
  $('#fig').on('click','img', function(){
    $(this).addClass("imgbig");
    $('.xbutton').stop(true, true).fadeTo(800,1);
    $("#fig").stop(true, true).addClass("f1");
  });

  $('#fig').on('click', '.xbutton', function(){
    // this line may be wrong depending on where your button is in relation to the image
    $(this).stop(true, true).fadeOut(800, 0).find('.imgSmall').removeClass('imgbig');
    $('#fig').stop(true, true).removeClass("f1");
  });
});
```

**Note:** I changed imgSmall to a class as I am guessing all small images have the same class, IDs should always be unique.